# Rule of thumb for Max Postgres connections to set?

Tags: postgresql

As a rule of thumb, how many max connections should I set my Postgres server to have? For instance, if I have 8 GB of memory, and quad core 3.2 GHZ machine, and the server is dedicated to only Postgres, how many max connections would be safe?

Comment: Read [`this`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) article. Especially the last part - "How to Find the Optimal Database Connection Pool Size".

Answer (score 5):

There is no real rule of thumb since it really depends on your load.

- If you do lots of tiny queries than you can easily increase the amount of connections.
- If you have a few heavy queries, than you will probably increase the `work_mem` so you'll run out of memory with a lot of connections.

The basic thing is:

- don't have more connections than your memory allows.
- don't kill and recreate connections if possible (pgbouncer springs to mind)

Comment: Definitely look at including [PgBouncer](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer) in your stack. A good deal of the connection overhead comes simply from starting up and closing down connections and this, whether run on the DB Server, the App Server (or both) can seriously improve resource utilization.